# Настройка Tor Expert Bundle windows 7/8/10

Tags: dns

Скачал распаковал Tor **Expert** Bundle. Настрои его в качестве win32 сервиса вот так

```
D:\path\to\tor.exe" --nt-service "-f" "D:/path/to/Tor/Data/Tor/torrc"
```

Сам **torrc** выглядит так:

```
 ExcludeNodes {ru}, {ua}, {by}
 DNSPort 9053
 AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
 AutomapHostsSuffixes .exit,.onion
```

сервис работает.

Прописал в качестве SOCKS5 прокси в Firefox.
Все работает:

1. https://check.torproject.org/
   выдает

> Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.

2. https://2ip.ru/ определяет совсем другую страну и не видит прокси.

НО при попытке перехода например на рутрекер.орг или еще какой нибудь заблокированный ресурс вижу страницу своего провайдера что доступ к данному ресурсу запрещен! Думаю дело в том что у меня не настроены DNS тора и видимо по этому тоже я не могу переходить на .onion домены. Или дело не в этом? Как все настроить?

Comment: А не может ли быть так, что браузер DNS запросы шлет в обход прокси?

Comment: Нет. Провайдер что-то мутил с DNS. Даже когда ставишь гугловские DNS в настройках протокола. Я плохо понимаю в сетях и что конкретно он делает предположить не могу. Решением было обновить до последней версии, поставить DNSPort 53, и в настройка сети прописать DNS server 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение - обновить до последней версии.